# trouble installing vtiger crm 6.4.0 on xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, vtigercrm

I have downloaded Vtiger CRM from https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtigercrm.

After downloading, I tried to install in my localhost XAMPP server.

1. I extracted the tar.gz file.
2. I couldn't find any database file inside the folder
3. While I ran the vtiger crm folder in localhost, many errors are coming. No installation page appears.

These are the error messages. Which settings to change in my XAMPP server can somebody tell.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: authenticated_user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\main\WebUI.php on line 44

Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: current_language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\Globals.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined property: Install_Index_view::$viewer in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\Controller.php on line 117

Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: theme in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31


Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670
```

Installation Wizard

```
Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670
```

Welcome
Help-Icon
Vtiger Logo

```
Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670
```

Welcome to Vtiger CRM 6 Setup Wizard

```
Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: file in   C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670
This wizard will guide you through the installation of Vtiger CRM6
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: language in    <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br /><br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: action in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php</b> on line <b>670</b><br /><br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php</b> on line <b>670</b><br />Install


Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\LanguageHandler.php on line 157
Powered by vtiger CRM 6.4.0   © 2004 - 2016   vtiger.com  |  
Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\LanguageHandler.php on line 157
Read License  |  
Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 670

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\includes\runtime\LanguageHandler.php on line 157
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable this error message just add one line in top of index.php file and run again CRM to install it.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

After successful installation you can remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the prerequisites are met?

```
MYSQL Requirements

Please make sure to review MySQL configuration (my.cnf or server start parameters)

SQL_MODE    Should not have STRICT_TRANS_TABLE
ENGINE=InnoDB   Should be available. (Turn off –skip-innodb)

PHP Extensions

Following extensions should be enabled for your PHP setup

GD  Mandatory   Charts and graphs generation are dependent on this library.
IMAP    Mandatory   Webmails Module is dependent on this library.
Zlib    Mandatory
OpenSSL Optional    Imap with OpenSSL should be enabled in case Mail server needs to be connected via SSL
Curl    Optional
```

After installing XAMPP stop all services and using notepad configure PHP.ini (inside php folder xampp installation) with the following values:

```
PHP Configuration

Make sure to verify if your PHP configuration meets the recommended values.

Variable    Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference  on
error_reporting E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
safe_mode   off
display_errors  on
file_uploads    on
max_execution_time  600
memory_limit    64M
log_errors  off
output_buffering    on      
short_open_tag  On
 allow_call_time_pass_reference on
register_globals    off
```

You should also check the permissions of files.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

These are just warning and notices so search in your php.ini file in xampp->php->php.ini for error_reporting=On and turn it off as error_reporting=Off. Then restart your xampp server and once restart your system also. Then try hope it will work . The same problem i had and i solved it in above way.

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini 
 error_reporting = E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT